# How to get/set highcharts xAxis step?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have succeeded in assigning a chart to my object variable "chart". And variable "iSteps" has a value. So why doesn't this work? (Note: I use regular javascript, not jquery style javascript.)

```
chart.xAxis[0].update ({ step : iSteps });
```

or

```
chart.xAxis[0].labels.update ({ step : iSteps });
```

or

```
chart.xAxis[0].labels[0].update ({ step : iSteps });
```

or

```
chart.xAxis[0].options.update ({ step : iSteps });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right syntax is

```
chart.xAxis[0].update ({labels: { step : iSteps }});
```

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have been able to figure that out. Wish I had been able to find that in the documentation.